# Clarification of data written in a resource bundle - Java

Tags: java, resources

The problem is not in english so this is my translation:

It often happens that games create resource bundles. They are one large binary file, consisting of TOC(table of contents) and the game resources written one after another with no compression. Make a program that reads such a resource bundle and extracts the files from it, while maintaining the directory structure.

Here is the example of a resource bundle:

```
///

/// Header

///

DWORD: Header      //BNDL

DWORD: Version     //0x02

ULONG: TOC size    //

///

/// TOC markers

///

byte:

01 - file name (zero terminated string). If the string 
starts with char 0x01, then it is a directory

02 - file info (ulong - offset from beginning of the file, 

DWORD – file size in bytes)

03 - move to parent directory

00000010 0101 6461 7461 0001 0161 6E69 6D73 0001 ..data...anims..

00000020 0167 686F 7374 0002 FCBD 1C02 0000 0000 .ghost..........

00000030 823D 7000 0167 686F 7374 5F6D 6163 6869 .=p..ghost_machi

00000040 6E65 2E78 6D62 00                        ne.xmb.         

string     filename = data/anims/ghost/ghost_machine.xmb

ulong      offset = 0x00000000021cbdfc

DWORD      filesize = 0x000703D82

------------------------------------------------------

000001C5 0301 0167 7569 0002 308A 2E01 0000 0000 ...gui..0.......

000001D5 52D7 0200 0161 6C65 7274 2E78 6D62 00    R....alert.xmb. 

0301 0167 7569 00 - go to the parent directory and enter 

directory “gui”

string     filename = data/gui/alert.xmb

ulong      offset = 0x012E8A30

DWORD      filesize = 0x0002D752
```

Where:

```
ulong (8 byte) = long

DWORD (4 byte) = int
```

I understand that I have to do some extraction, but can't get the meaning behind the stuff witten in the file. What is the text in the example showing?

Comment: what have you tried? I recommend you starting reading the Bundle data, then find the lines that tell you where other files are located...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file content consists of data in 0 and 1.

First you have HEADER - which are 4 bytes ... each byte creates one character - value is set to BNDL e.g. 4 bytes

see what numbers are used for saving characters there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII?ASCII_control_code_chart#ASCII_printable_code_chart

next is version string: 0x02

and then 8 byte long integer which says how many bytes follow

next we have example of data! and see that whenever there is 01 - that means new file or folder, if we have 02 we have some file information, and when we have 03 - that means we move to parent. This describes folder structure in which all files are saved (in this file).

`00000010 0101 6461 7461 0001 0161 6E69 6D73 0001 ..data...anims..`

this line says that these data start at 16th bit (00000010 in hex), that in bytes data are: 010164617461000101616E696D730001 in hexadecimal - which means each pair of numbers form one byte, and then we see ..data...anims.. which shows us any readable characters (and dot for any unreadable)

ps. hope this clarifies some basics, ask if something is not clear enough

Comment: So when reading from the file when should I read in sizes long and int?

Comment: Also can you clarify on the second file as well. Thanks :)

Comment: @user3719857 Well, short answer: DWORD corresponds to int and ulong to long

Comment: @user3719857 I am not sure what you mean by 'second file'. You have only one HUGE file, in which you find directory structure and contents of all files inside this structure. If you mean the last part in your example, thats just another part of the file starting at 1C5-th byte.

Comment: I mean when reading this `00000010` should it be int ot long? I think it should be int.

Comment: For the second question- what I understand is that `000001C5` shows me where in the files is the data for a file with name `01 6461 7461`   Is this correct?

Comment: You should not read `00000010` or `000001C5` - these hex numbers show you where in the file are data shown further in that particular line. E.g. `00000010 0101 6461 7461 0001 0161 6E69 6D73 0001` tells you that first 01 and second 01 are 16th and 17th bytes in the file.

Comment: Lets say I wan't to construct the file in the first or second example. What should be my steps , because I didn't quite get what you are saying in the last comment.

Comment: First you read the PATH ... read one byte ... see if  it is 01 (means path follows), then read another byte - if it is 01 then it is folder - you read until a byte is not 00. You repeat described step until you read 02 instead of 01. Then you know you now should read **long offset** and **int size**. These two numbers tell you where in this file described file bytes is located - offset tells you which byte is first byte of that file, and size tells you how many bytes belong to that file. After that you expect 01 to tell you what is name of the file.

Comment: And each time you load 03 you remove last entry from the stack (which would be appropriate to implement this)

Comment: I got the part with `01`, `02` and `03`, but the  `00000010`, `00000020`, `00000030` and so on , confuse me. What is their purpose in all of this ?

Comment: Numbers like `00000010` are in your example just for illustrative puropse. It denotes what is the number of the first byte on respective line. Similar to line numbers when you edit text file, this is just to clarify _where_ in the file you are. This concept is used quite often for binary files, see this hexedit screenshot for illustration http://www.catch22.net/sites/default/files/hex1.jpg

Comment: Aha Ok I get it thanks :) It's a good thing they won't be in the file :)

Comment: Last question. When we have `03` we move to the parent directory, which is from the first entry, from  `data/anims/ghost` to `data/anims`. But in the example it is `data` to which we add the folder `gui` to make `data/gui/...`. Shouldn't it be `data/anims/gui...` , or when we say parent directory we mean the top level one ?

Comment: Not sure, but my guess would be this: since considerable part of the file was cut out, some operations might have changed root to  `data` ... So I would stick with _go to parent_ of current path